# Android - How to disable RecyclerView auto scroll from clicking

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Since API 24, the `RecyclerView` will auto scroll to a item which is displayed in partial by the user click the item.
How to disable this feature?

The codes below works before `support-library 25.0.1`.

```
@Override
    public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate) {
        Object tag = child.getTag();
        if( tag != null && tag.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("preventAutoScroll") ){
            return false;
        }
        return super.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(child, rect, immediate);
    }
```

It has to be focusable and clickable, because it's a `TextView` and the text needs to be selectable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set an overriden version of the layout manager on recycler view. In my case I wanted to disable for when a certain child view was focused e.g.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
        @Override
        public boolean requestChildRectangleOnScreen(RecyclerView parent, View child, Rect rect, boolean immediate, boolean focusedChildVisible) {

            if (((ViewGroup) child).getFocusedChild() instanceof YourFocusableChildViewClass) {                    
                return false;
            }

            return super.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(parent, child, rect, immediate, focusedChildVisible);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I don't have this method in the RecyclerView, do you use a third-party library?

Comment: I found it in the `LayoutManager`. Works like a charm!

Comment: Where can I find `YourFocusableChildViewClass` ?

Comment: YourFocusableChildViewClass  =For Ex= > EditText

Answer (score 0):

A solution which works across the whole app

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, set activity's `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

This prevents the layout from being resized when the soft keyboard appears, stopping the automatic scrolling.

`adjustpan` [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) :

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.